# Multiple extra-cflags of a makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, ffmpeg

so there is this library am trying to use [ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/) and am customizing the `Makefile`. I have done everything that I wanted to do but on building, I got the error `ERROR: opus not found using pkg-config`. Now I have two problems:

`--extra-cflags="-s USE_ZLIB=1 -I../lame/dist/include -I../libvpx/dist/include"` this configuration was initially `--extra-cflags="-s USE_ZLIB=1 -I../lame/dist/include"` but I wanted to include two folders, so is the merging correct or that's where I went wrong.

The complete `Makefile` is as below (there are alot of changes from the original one from the repository), is there anything I did wrong?

```
PRE_JS = build/pre.js
POST_JS_SYNC = build/post-sync.js

COMMON_FILTERS = aresample scale crop overlay hstack vstack
COMMON_DEMUXERS = matroska ogg mov mp3 wav image2 concat
COMMON_DECODERS = vp8 vp9 h264 vorbis opus mp3 aac pcm_s16le mjpeg png

COMMON_BSFS = vp9_superframe

MUXERS = mp4 mp3 webm ogg null
ENCODERS = libx264 libmp3lame aac libvpx_vp8 libopus
FFMPEG_BC = build/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.bc
FFMPEG_PC_PATH = ../x264/dist/lib/pkgconfig
SHARED_DEPS = \
    build/lame/dist/lib/libmp3lame.so \
    build/x264/dist/lib/libx264.so \
    build/opus/dist/lib/libopus.so \
    build/libvpx/dist/lib/libvpx.so

all: ffmpeg.js

clean: clean-js \
    clean-opus clean-libvpx clean-lame \
    clean-x264 clean-ffmpeg
clean-js:
    rm -f ffmpeg*.js
clean-opus:
    cd build/opus && git clean -xdf
clean-libvpx:
    cd build/libvpx && git clean -xdf
clean-lame:
    cd build/lame && git clean -xdf
clean-x264:
    cd build/x264 && git clean -xdf
clean-ffmpeg:
    cd build/ffmpeg-mp4 && git clean -xdf

build/opus/configure:
    cd build/opus && ./autogen.sh

build/opus/dist/lib/libopus.so: build/opus/configure
    cd build/opus && \
    emconfigure ./configure \
        CFLAGS=-O3 \
        --prefix="$$(pwd)/dist" \
        --disable-static \
        --disable-doc \
        --disable-extra-programs \
        --disable-asm \
        --disable-rtcd \
        --disable-intrinsics \
        --disable-hardening \
        --disable-stack-protector \
        && \
    emmake make -j && \
    emmake make install

build/libvpx/dist/lib/libvpx.so:
    cd build/libvpx && \
    git reset --hard && \
    patch -p1 < ../libvpx-fix-ld.patch && \
    emconfigure ./configure \
        --prefix="$$(pwd)/dist" \
        --target=generic-gnu \
        --disable-dependency-tracking \
        --disable-multithread \
        --disable-runtime-cpu-detect \
        --enable-shared \
        --disable-static \
        \
        --disable-examples \
        --disable-docs \
        --disable-unit-tests \
        --disable-webm-io \
        --disable-libyuv \
        --disable-vp8-decoder \
        --disable-vp9 \
        && \
    emmake make -j && \
    emmake make install

build/lame/dist/lib/libmp3lame.so:
    cd build/lame/lame && \
    git reset --hard && \
    patch -p2 < ../../lame-fix-ld.patch && \
    emconfigure ./configure \
        CFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -O3" \
        --prefix="$$(pwd)/../dist" \
        --host=x86-none-linux \
        --disable-static \
        \
        --disable-gtktest \
        --disable-analyzer-hooks \
        --disable-decoder \
        --disable-frontend \
        && \
    emmake make -j && \
    emmake make install

build/x264/dist/lib/libx264.so:
    cd build/x264 && \
    emconfigure ./configure \
        --prefix="$$(pwd)/dist" \
        --extra-cflags="-Wno-unknown-warning-option" \
        --host=x86-none-linux \
        --disable-cli \
        --enable-shared \
        --disable-opencl \
        --disable-thread \
        --disable-interlaced \
        --bit-depth=8 \
        --chroma-format=420 \
        --disable-asm \
        \
        --disable-avs \
        --disable-swscale \
        --disable-lavf \
        --disable-ffms \
        --disable-gpac \
        --disable-lsmash \
        && \
    emmake make -j && \
    emmake make install

FFMPEG_COMMON_ARGS = \
    --cc=emcc \
    --ranlib=emranlib \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --target-os=none \
    --arch=x86 \
    --disable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --disable-asm \
    --disable-fast-unaligned \
    --disable-pthreads \
    --disable-w32threads \
    --disable-os2threads \
    --disable-debug \
    --disable-stripping \
    --disable-safe-bitstream-reader \
    \
    --disable-all \
    --enable-ffmpeg \
    --enable-avcodec \
    --enable-avformat \
    --enable-avfilter \
    --enable-swresample \
    --enable-swscale \
    --disable-network \
    --disable-d3d11va \
    --disable-dxva2 \
    --disable-vaapi \
    --disable-vdpau \
    $(addprefix --enable-bsf=,$(COMMON_BSFS)) \
    $(addprefix --enable-decoder=,$(COMMON_DECODERS)) \
    $(addprefix --enable-demuxer=,$(COMMON_DEMUXERS)) \
    --enable-protocol=file \
    $(addprefix --enable-filter=,$(COMMON_FILTERS)) \
    --disable-bzlib \
    --disable-iconv \
    --disable-libxcb \
    --disable-lzma \
    --disable-sdl2 \
    --disable-securetransport \
    --disable-xlib \
    --enable-zlib

build/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.bc: $(SHARED_DEPS)
    cd build/ffmpeg-mp4 && \
    EM_PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(FFMPEG_PC_PATH) emconfigure ./configure \
        $(FFMPEG_COMMON_ARGS) \
        $(addprefix --enable-encoder=,$(ENCODERS)) \
        $(addprefix --enable-muxer=,$(MUXERS)) \
        --enable-gpl \
        --enable-libmp3lame \
        --enable-libx264 \
        --enable-libopus \
        --enable-libvpx \
        --extra-cflags="-s USE_ZLIB=1 -I../lame/dist/include -I../libvpx/dist/include" \
        --extra-ldflags="-L../lame/dist/lib -L../libvpx/dist/lib" \
        && \
    emmake make -j && \
    cp ffmpeg ffmpeg.bc

EMCC_COMMON_ARGS = \
    -O3 \
    --closure 1 \
    --memory-init-file 0 \
    -s WASM=0 \
    -s WASM_ASYNC_COMPILATION=0 \
    -s ASSERTIONS=0 \
    -s EXIT_RUNTIME=1 \
    -s NODEJS_CATCH_EXIT=0 \
    -s NODEJS_CATCH_REJECTION=0 \
    -s TOTAL_MEMORY=67108864 \
    -lnodefs.js -lworkerfs.js \
    --pre-js $(PRE_JS) \
    -o $@

ffmpeg.js: $(FFMPEG_BC) $(PRE_JS) $(POST_JS_SYNC)
    emcc $(FFMPEG_BC) $(SHARED_DEPS) \
        --post-js $(POST_JS_SYNC) \
        $(EMCC_COMMON_ARGS) -O2
```

What I was trying to achieve was combine some of the webm encoders and muxers into the mp4 module so I use only that one module for all webm and mp4 format types.

Also one thing to know about me, the whole Makefile and C and building it is totally new territory for me, I just did what I thought was right, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's good you have solid goals.  Without those, the problem is much harder.

What you need to do is understand the commands you would run, without make or Makefiles, to achieve those goals, and the files that are created along the way.  With this, you then encode those commands in the format

```
file_to_be_created:source_file_1 source_file_2 source_file_3
<tab>command to be executed
<tab>second command to be executed
```

The tabs are an unfortunate side-effect of a bad choice in make's history.

With this, you can modify the Makefile.  If you have one source that is built from other sources, make two "make" rules using the pattern above, and make will correctly determine the build order and run the commands needed.  If make determines a crated file is newer than its sources, it will skip building the created file.

As you can see, while make is not very complicated, it does little to help you know the commands you must run.  Maybe you know them already; but, if you don't I'd take your personal knowledge and what you can read out of the Makefile and combine them to see if you can fashion the make file rules you need.

Initially, I'd do this by creating new rules and new files, because if you break a rule you need, odds are you won't find out until much later.  Once you get something building, you can review if you should roll you rules into some of the existing ones or not.

Good luck!

Comment: The thing is am totally new to this, so the commands, flags, options, i don't know them

Comment: @lulliezy Unfortunately, there's little chance that I can guess what rules you need, as it varies from organization to organization, team to team, and project to project.  I would recommend finding someone within your group that knows a bit more about this item and asking them.  If such a person doesn't exist, you may have to hire someone with general skills in this area, put them on the project, and have them read over the items until they can make an educated guess, adjusting from there, if necessary.

Comment: Actually i wanted to have webm support to mp4 module @Edwin

Comment: @lulliezy Saying what you want to do and how you are going to do it are two very different things.  Makefiles will only automate the latter.  Makefiles won't help you find out how to accomplish the task (unless you can identify another's accomplishment of a similar task and modify it)  Maybe you could start with understanding what files you want as the output, and deduce what's in them (and how to get the contents in there)